# CSS: How to make one element react to a hover of a element that is after it

Tags: html, css, hover

I did a very simple demo in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/pp23kzhv/9/) to illustrate my question.

I have two squares: a red `#square1` and a blue `#square2`. What I want is very simple: when you hover the red square the other one turns red, and the same for the blue square.

The first one worked, using this code:

```
#square1:hover + #square2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The next effect did not work though. Used the `~` as I thought that that is what I should use for elements that are declared before?

```
#square2:hover ~ #square1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

How can I make it work using only CSS?

Comment: No..there is no [**previous sibling**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector) selector.

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS because CSS cannot traverse the DOM backward. You need JavaScript.

Comment: @Joca Pinto u can mask square through :after/:before other square

Comment: Did it with javascript, thanks for the help